# How can I see how many Bitcoins my c-lightning network node has?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

I am running a c-lightning node and want to know how many btc I am owning on this wallet and how many I can spend. `lightning-cli listchannels` does not help. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [RPC-Interface listfunds](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/doc/lightning-listfunds.7.txt) `lightning-cli listfunds` which lists all payment channels and UTXO.

If you wish to have a more nicely display you can use this small tool: https://github.com/renepickhardt/lightning-helpers

```
git clone https://github.com/renepickhardt/lightning-helpers.git

cd lightning-helpers
sudo make install
listfunds
```

it aggregates everything so that you can see your total funds. Also you can add a parameter to change the unit of display.

If you don't trust a third party tool and don't want to read the source code you can use this little shell script:

utxo values:

`lightning-cli listfunds | grep "value" | sed 's/      "value": //g' | sed 's/,//g' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

total channel balance on your side:

`lightning-cli listfunds | grep "channel_sat" | sed 's/      "channel_sat": //g' | sed 's/,//g' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

Answer (score 1):

If you have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed, you can ask it to sum up all the values for you. For example, to get the total amount stored in your node’s UTXOs:

```
lightning-cli listfunds | jq '[.outputs[].value] | add'
```

If you want your output in BTC rather than satoshis, you can divide it right away:

```
lightning-cli listfunds | jq '[.outputs[].value] | add / 100000000'
```

Comment: `lightning-cli listfunds | jq '[.channels[].channel_sat] | add / 100000000'` for the btc in channels on your side